# Present simple even if it is not a general statement

Tags: present-tense

I came across this sentence:

> When I go home tonight, I lay down in my bed and turn on the TV and it makes me so glad.

I think future shall be used  (will  or going to) for lay down, turn on and make.
Present shall not be used for these verbs because it is not a general statement (tonight)

What do you think of it?

Answer (score 4):

You are correct in thinking future tense should be used. This would make the quote: "When I go home tonight, I *will lie* down in my bed and turn on the TV and it *will make* me so glad". However, this sentence feels bulky because of the chained clauses ("and ... and ... and"). I would say something along the lines of "When I go home tonight, I will lie down in my bed, turn on the TV and [feel happy/relax]"

Comment: Are you sure the verb is "to lay", not "to lie"?

Comment: I would use them interchangeably in conversation, but it should be "will lie", yes

Comment: And there is no need to repeat will before turn on and make ?

Comment: there is no need to repeat "will", no as the tense applies to the whole end of the sentence

Comment: If "I lay down in my bed" is present tense, then it means I apply duck feathers.  The present tense verb you want is "lie down".

Answer (score 2):

> When I go home tonight, I am going to lie down on the bed and just relax.

I would use *going to* since it seems a well-devised plan, not a spontaneously given answer. But both are fine, really.

The present simple is commonly used to tell stories.

> When I go home tonight... *(you close your eyes, your imagination kicks in)* I take off my clothes, I dim the lights, I pour a glass of wine...

which puts the listener in the moment and has a dramatic (or often comedic) effect.